# JavaScript function changes does not appear in JSNI

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I am changing JavaScript function in JSNI but eventlistener not call properly. Here is the code:

```java
private native void alert1()/*-{
    $doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function webViewerLoad(evt) {
        $wnd.alert("1111111");
    }, true);
}-*/;
```

Javascript function is :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function webViewerLoad(evt) {
    window.alert("2222222222");
}, true);
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onModuleLoad` is (almost) guaranteed to run **after** `DOMContentLoaded`, so:

- you don't need to listen for that even in your code
- if you do, it's too late and you event handler won't ever be called

Comment: Actually when i call this JSNI method than alert not show and in my application i have approx 200 lines of code for execute. I don't understand problem is 'DomContentLoaded' ar $wnd ar $doc?

Comment: The core problem is that the event has already fired! It's like going to a New Year's Eve party after midnight: the fireworks are already gone, you can wait for them for long! (and contrary to New Year's Eve, `DOMContentLoaded` is not a recurring event)